# Simple event observer not working in

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, event-observer

even my complete module was working with default installation.

---

config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Barcatsia_Smsntf>
                <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module -->
            </Barcatsia_Smsntf>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <smsntf>
                    <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Block</class>  <!-- Path of the
     Block Folder, where all php files are located related to view -->
                </smsntf>
            </blocks>
            <helpers>
                <smsntf>
                    <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Helper</class> 
    <!-- Path of Helper Files -->
                </smsntf>
            </helpers>
    <!-- Observer event register -->
        <events>            
               <!--  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> -->
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                    <observers>
                        <Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>customFunction</method>
                        </Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer>
                    </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
               <!--  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> -->
            </events>
    <!-- Observer event register -->
        </global>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <smsntf>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Barcatsia_Smsntf</module>
                        <frontName>smsntf</frontName>  <!-- This is the URL
     of the module. i.e www.yourmagento.com/index.php/test will be the url of your module. -->
                    </args>
                </smsntf>
            </routers>
            <layout>  <!-- New Section Added -->
                <updates>
                    <smsntf>
                        <file>smsntf.xml</file> <!-- This is name of the layout file for this module -->
                    </smsntf>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
        <adminhtml>       
            <acl>
                <resources>
                    <admin>
                        <children>
                            <system>
                                <children>
                                    <config>
                                        <children>
                                            <testsection translate="title" module="smsntf">
                                                <title>SMS Notification</title>
                                            </testsection>
                                        </children>
                                    </config>
                                </children>
                            </system>
                        </children>
                    </admin>
                </resources>
            </acl>        
        </adminhtml>
    </config>
```

Model/observer.php

```
  <?php
    class Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer
    {
        public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
          echo "asssssssssadddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try after clearing your cache from `System > Cache`

Comment: but cache is disbaled

Comment: Then define model in `config.xml`

Comment: can you tell me in which tag ? is it global?

Comment: its still not working

Comment: Check my answer i have updated xml in my answer

Comment: Maybe the 'observer.php' file name should start with a capital letter like this 'Observer.php'

Comment: add you observer class like this class Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer{  public function customFunction($observer){ echo "Yes";} }

Comment: i hope this will work, check my previous comment

Comment: Is it working for you or still you are facing issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `config.xml` with following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Barcatsia_Smsntf>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module -->
        </Barcatsia_Smsntf>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <smsntf>
                <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model</class>
            </smsntf>
        </models>

        <blocks>
            <smsntf>
                <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Block</class>  <!-- Path of the
 Block Folder, where all php files are located related to view -->
            </smsntf>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <smsntf>
                <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Helper</class> 
<!-- Path of Helper Files -->
            </smsntf>
        </helpers>
<!-- Observer event register -->
    <events>            
           <!--  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> -->
    <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customFunction</method>
                    </Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_load_before>
           <!--  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> -->
        </events>
<!-- Observer event register -->
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <smsntf>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Barcatsia_Smsntf</module>
                    <frontName>smsntf</frontName>  <!-- This is the URL
 of the module. i.e www.yourmagento.com/index.php/test will be the url of your module. -->
                </args>
            </smsntf>
        </routers>
        <layout>  <!-- New Section Added -->
            <updates>
                <smsntf>
                    <file>smsntf.xml</file> <!-- This is name of the layout file for this module -->
                </smsntf>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>       
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <testsection translate="title" module="smsntf">
                                            <title>SMS Notification</title>
                                        </testsection>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>        
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Rename your observer file from `observer.php` to **`Observer.php`**

Also disable your compilation from `System > Tools > Compilation`

Hope it helps you

Comment: sorry but it did not working

Comment: check Moving your observer from `global` tag to `frontend`.

Comment: only observer? i mean not event ?

Comment: well i did it but still not working. its making me mad  code was working on default installtion

Comment: I mean your event code. Is there any error in error log?

Comment: 2016-02-02T06:34:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 11: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: classs line 11 and class  in /home/onnik/public_html/test/includes/src/__default.php on line 22592

Comment: Ohh got. Now please update my answered `config.xml` with yours. This error coming because there is some problem in defining any xml tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35151/discussion-between-rahul-chaurasia-and-rohit-kundale).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Barcatsia_Smsntf>
                <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module -->
            </Barcatsia_Smsntf>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <smsntf>
                    <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model</class>
                </smsntf>
            </models>
            <blocks>
                <smsntf>
                    <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Block</class>  <!-- Path of the
     Block Folder, where all php files are located related to view -->
                </smsntf>
            </blocks>
            <helpers>
                <smsntf>
                    <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Helper</class> 
    <!-- Path of Helper Files -->
                </smsntf>
            </helpers>
    <!-- Observer event register -->
        <events>            
               <!--  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> -->
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                    <observers>
                        <Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>customFunction</method>
                        </Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer>
                    </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
               <!--  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> -->
            </events>
    <!-- Observer event register -->
        </global>
        <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <hooksystem_order_success>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>hooksystem/observer</class>
                    <method>hookToOrderSaveEvent</method>
                    </hooksystem_order_success>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        </events>

            <routers>
                <smsntf>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Barcatsia_Smsntf</module>
                        <frontName>smsntf</frontName>  <!-- This is the URL
     of the module. i.e www.yourmagento.com/index.php/test will be the url of your module. -->
                    </args>
                </smsntf>
            </routers>
            <layout>  <!-- New Section Added -->
                <updates>
                    <smsntf>
                        <file>smsntf.xml</file> <!-- This is name of the layout file for this module -->
                    </smsntf>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
        <adminhtml>       
            <acl>
                <resources>
                    <admin>
                        <children>
                            <system>
                                <children>
                                    <config>
                                        <children>
                                            <testsection translate="title" module="smsntf">
                                                <title>SMS Notification</title>
                                            </testsection>
                                        </children>
                                    </config>
                                </children>
                            </system>
                        </children>
                    </admin>
                </resources>
            </acl>        
        </adminhtml>
    </config>
```

Only add `models` section under the `global` section

```
<models>
                <smsntf>
                    <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model</class>
                </smsntf>
            </models>
```

Comment: it didnt working

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it is working for me.

config.xml

```
<controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers>
                <barcatsia_bmsntf_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>bmsntf/observer</class>
                    <method>customFunction</method>
                </barcatsia_bmsntf_model_observer>
            </observers>
</controller_action_layout_load_before>
```

Observer.php

```
public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
echo "Do what you want";
exit;

}
```